# Number of Order From Customers

Tags: tableau-api

This seems like a simple question but I'm having trouble building my graph. I'm trying to get the number of customers who made 1 order, 2 orders, 3 orders etc..

Sample Data Source:

```
Customer ID| Order ID| Date Ordered

A               10        06/01/2019
A               11        06/02/2019
A               12        06/02/2019
B               15        06/05/2019
B               16        06/05/2019
B               17        06/05/2019
C               20        06/06/2019 
C               21        06/06/2019
```

I can easily get the graph to show that Customer A made 3 Orders , Customer B made 3 Orders and Customer C made 2 orders.. etc.

What I'm trying to show is how many customer places a certain number of orders . So in our sample data. 1 Order = 0 , 2 Orders = 1, 3 Orders = 2. So in the X axis im trying to show (1 Order, 2 Orders , 3 Orders, 4 Orders.. etc )

I tried doing calculations such as IF COUNT([CustomerID]) > 2 then '1 order' but I can't seem to get it right.  Any advice will be helpful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try using [LOD expressions](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod.htm) and create a new calculated field like this:

```
{INCLUDE [Customer ID]: COUNTD([Order ID])}
```

And then use that field to show that info.

Comment: Hi dubafek thanks for the feedback. I'm created a calculate field [numberoforder] as you suggested and on the data I'm able to see that it's calculating correctly. However I'm having trouble displaying the graph. on the X axis im trying to display how the number of order "1 Order" , "2 Order", "3 Order" and on the Y i'm trying to display number of customers. I tried using a calculation such as If [Numberoforder] = 1 then "1 order" etc.. When I create this calculation i'm unable to drag it to dimension .. any suggestions?